# "The operation could not be completed. An unknown error occurred (-12880)" when using AVPlayer

Tags: video, ios8, avplayer

I have been getting the following error when using AVPlayer to play 2 consecutive videos:

"The operation could not be completed. An unknown error occurred (-12880)"

This usually happens when 1 video is finished playing and about to start another video. On Apple's documentation I cannot find the error code -12880. Does anyone by any chance know what this error code means?

I am on iOS8.

Comment: have you got any solution for this?